# Traduzir formato longo de data de inglês para português

Tags: java, android, data

Estou convertendo uma String para Data

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                        Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date convertDate = new Date();
                String dd = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DATA_NOTICIA");

                try{
                    convertDate = dateFormat.parse(dd);
                }catch(ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

E passando ela para uma listView, na listView ela aparece assim: `Wed Jul 13 16:52:48 GMT 2016`
Tem como traduzir essa data para português?
Não encontrei uma maneira, alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O formato de apresentação das datas difere de país/idioma para país/idioma.

Para se obter o formato para o país/idioma desejado tem de se informar ao *SimpleDateFormat* o respectivo *Locale*.

Use este método para fazer mudanças de Locale:

```
public static String formatDateToLocale(String data, String formato,
                                        Locale localeEntrada, Locale localeSaida) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat(formato, localeEntrada);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatSaida = new SimpleDateFormat(formato, localeSaida);

    Date dataOriginal;
    String novoFormato = null;

    try {

        dataOriginal = dateFormatEntrada.parse(data);
        novoFormato = dateFormatSaida.format(dataOriginal);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return novoFormato;
}
```

Use assim:

```
String data = formatDateToLocale("Wed Jul 13 16:52:48 GMT 2016","EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                 Locale.ENGLISH, new Locale("pt","BR"));
```